# Illegal start of expression when making class for module (java)

Tags: java, class, module, illegalstateexception

I created a module that's called within another module, and it looks something like this:

```
 public static double calculateAnswer (double itemRadius, String itemShape);

{ 
  double circleArea; 

  if (itemShape.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
  {

    circleArea = 3.14159 * (itemRadius * itemRadius);

    System.out.print("The area of the circle in inches is "  + circleArea);

    return circleArea;
  }


    else 
    {

         calculateAnswerSphere (itemRadius);
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////// seperating method
    public static double calculateAnswerSphere(double itemRadius);
    {
      double sphereVolume;

      sphereVolume = (4.0/3) * 3.14159 * (itemRadius * itemRadius * itemRadius);

      system.out.print("The volume of the sphere in cubic inches is " +sphereVolume);
    }

    end If;
```

but, I'm getting the error of "illegal start of expression" with the line where I make the method header for the second module.  It looks constructed correctly.

Complete code as follows:

```
//This program will find the area or volume of a circle or sphere, respectively.

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Java_Chapter_9

{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {

    //Declarations

    String itemShape;   //type of shape
    String runProgram;   //user control
    Double itemRadius;  //radius of tem
    Double finalAnswer;  //calculation for final answer

//End Declarations

showGreeting ();  //Call greeting module

runProgram = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 'Y' to run the program, or 'N' to quit");  //giving user control

while (runProgram.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) //loop for continuous use

{
  itemShape = getItemShape ();  //calling itemShape module

  itemRadius = getItemRadius ();  //calling itemradius module

  finalAnswer = calculateAnswer (itemRadius, itemShape);  //calling the module for calculation with paramaters

  runProgram = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 'Y' to input more, or 'N' to Quit");
}  

showGoodbye ();



////////////////////////////////////////////////// starting modules


public static void showGreeting ()  //greeting module

{

  System.out.println("Welcome to the program");
  System.out.println("This program will show you the area or volume of a shape");
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////// seperating modules
public static String getItemShape ()


{
  String typeOfShape;

  typeOfShape = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 'C' for a Circle, or 'S' for a Sphere"); //getting input for shape

  return typeOfShape; //returning to method

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////// seperating modules
public static double getItemRadius ()

{
  double radiusOfItem;  //variable withing scope of module
  String radiusOfItemInput;

  radiusOfItemInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the radius of the item in inches: ");

  radiusOfItem = Double.parseDouble(radiusOfItemInput);
  return radiusOfItem;    
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////// seperating modules  
public static double calculateAnswer (double itemRadius, String itemShape);

{ 
  double circleArea; 

  if (itemShape.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
  {

    circleArea = 3.14159 * (itemRadius * itemRadius);

    System.out.print("The area of the circle in inches is "  + circleArea);

    return circleArea;
  }


    else 
    {

         calculateAnswerSphere(itemRadius);
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////// seperating method


    public static double calculateAnswerSphere(double itemRadius);

    {
      double sphereVolume;

      sphereVolume = (4.0/3) * 3.14159 * (itemRadius * itemRadius * itemRadius);

      system.out.print("The volume of the sphere in cubic inches is " +sphereVolume);
    }

    end If;

}


public static void showGoodbye ()    
{
  System.out.println("Thank you for using the program. Goodbye.");

}
```

Specifically, I appear to be having problems in general calling the modules, but none of the text is overly clear and how to make a module fit within the main method, which is where I'm struggling.

Comment: What language is this in? Where do you get the error? Can you please edit your question to include those details, and also copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output. And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apologies.  I'm beyond new at any of this.  Post updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in your code.

1. Remove the `;` in function. `;` is not needed for function.

   ```
   public static double calculateAnswerSphere(double itemRadius); // remove ;
   ```
2. After `showGoodBye()` method is being called, you miss to add a close brackets.
3. You have a typo in this line

   ```
   system.out.print
   ```

It should be `System.out.print` and so on...